# How to rotate image in Android without using bitmap?

Tags: android, image, rotation, landscape

Captured Image stored in Landscape position so i want to change it to Potrait.

How to do this without using Bitmap?
If i use below code image get damaged.So only i want to do with out using bitmap.

My code is:

```
Bitmap Out = null;
Bitmap Output = null;

Out = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
int w = Out.getWidth();
int h = Out.getHeight();
 Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);

             Output = Bitmap.createBitmap(Out, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
               image = bitmaptoByte(Output);
```

Comment: if it's in a layout you can apply an animation to it, but if you want the actual image to rotate you have to use via Bitmap.

Comment: you could tell the Camera to save image in a specified orientation, but I did not find this property

Comment: @Budius If i use Bitmap image get damaged.So only i want to do without Bitmap.

Comment: @JerecTheSith Do u have any code to this property

Comment: If it's getting damage it's likely that the code is incorrect. Maybe you if post a question specific to rotate bitmaps, and show your code, someone can help you out.

Comment: @Budius I added My code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) 
For example, I rotate the second hand:

```
public RotateAnimation createAnimation(float time) {
      RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(time, time,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
      rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
      return rotateAnimation;

  public void runSec(float shour) {
      csecond.startAnimation(createAnimation(shour*6));
    }
```